# complexity of Bucket sort (uniform keys)

Tags: algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

```
The following table describes integer sorting algorithms and other sorting algorithms that are not comparison sorts. As such, they are not limited by a \Omega(n \log n) lower bound. Complexities below assume n items to be sorted, with keys of size k, digit size d, and r the range of numbers to be sorted. Many of them are based on the assumption that the key size is large enough that all entries have unique key values, and hence that n << 2k, where << means "much less than."
```

[image]

What does the k mean for Bucket sort (uniform keys)?

What does the r mean for Bucket sort (integer keys)? Why the complexity is affected by the range of numbers to be sorted?

Why they are different?

Comment: Not sure, but on the bucket sort page, they seem to use k as the number of bits they examine while partitionning the values.

Comment: You've included the answer in your question: `k` is the size of the keys. Also, as @user189 pointed out, it's present on the BucketSort wiki page

Comment: @user189 could you explain the reason why Bucket sort (integer keys) is affected by the range of numbers to be sorted? Thank you.

Comment: @blgt same question as mentioned above thank you.

Comment: @Linlin Ok, the terminology used could be a bit confusing. Note the table is *specific to integer sorting*. So, if i'm reading it correctly, instead of *uniform* it should say *partial* keys, and `k` would be their (the keys') range. For the second bucket sort, instead of *integer* it should say *non-partial* keys, in which case `k` goes all the way up to `r`. In this case, you can cut a bit of optimisations for the worst case, which is why it's `O(n+r)` rather than `O(rn^2)`

Comment: <continued> Actually, for the worst case you can not just cut *a bit* of optimising, you can optimise it away completely (as every bucket is guaranteed to never contain unsorted items)